# How to Exit (or Navigate out of )a MasterDetail page to a simple ContentPage in Xamarin. Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app which has the following:

```
LoginPage - a ContentPage type
RegisterPage - a ContentPage type

parentMasterDetail - a MasterDetailPage type
masterPage - Master page (ContentPage type)
AppointmentPage - Detail page (ContentPage type)
NewAppointment - Detail  page (ContentPage type)
```

I was able to create the pages all the pages as listed above, BUT

when I click on Logout button from the Detail page, 
the LoginPage displays but to my surprise it displayed just as a detail page, 
as if it is one of the detail pages and the menu page(i.e masterPage) is still 
accessible from my login page. This is not what I intended.

I want to logout of (i.e close) the MasterDetailPage, named parentMasterDetail, 
and navigate to the LoginPage which is not part of the MasterDetailPage such that 
the masterPage (i.e the menu) will not be accessible until user logs-in.

Please, anyone help me.

Comment: Could you maybe share some code?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

Comment: This PERFECTLY SOLVED MY PROBLEM! Having been frustrated searching the net without any clue, Thanks a Trillion!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need without top navigation bar (Header of Page), try this.

```
Application.Current.MainPage = (new UserLoginPage());
```