# How do I close an MvvmCross MasterDetail page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I would like my app to show a Login page, then a MasterDetail page with a 'hamburger' menu. On the hamburger menu I want a Log Out entry that closes the Master Detail and shows the Login page again. I have all but the log out part working.

I have copied code from the MvvmCross Playgrounds sample, specifically the MixedNavFirstPage (which fakes a login procedure), MixedNavMasterDetailPage (the 'hamburger menu'), and MixedNavMasterRootContentPage.

If I try to close the MixedNavMasterDetailPage with `await _navigationService.Close(this)` then I get a null reference exception in `MvxFormsPagePresenter.CloseMasterDetailPage()`

This question [How to Exit (or Navigate out of )a MasterDetail page to a simple ContentPage in Xamarin. Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918252/how-to-exit-or-navigate-out-of-a-masterdetail-page-to-a-simple-contentpage-in) covers what I want to do in straight Xamarin.Forms, I'm just not sure how to do the equivalent in MvvmCross.

Comment: I just tried `_navigationService.Navigate(typeof(LoginViewModel))`- where LoginViewModel is my equivalent of the Playground's MixedNavFirstPage -  and that seemed to work in that I got my login page again. But... on logging in a second time I don't get the master detail page again, just a blank page.

Comment: After reading c.lamont.dev's answer confirming I was on the right track I tried again with the `Navigate(typeof(LoginViewModel))` and it seemed to work. Perhaps another example of unreliable VS Mac/Android interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoginPage` add the `MvxContentPagePresentation` attribute `NoHistory = true`

Then simply navigate to the login page, and when the user has logged in, navigate to your MasterDetail page also with `NoHistory = true`.

When the user logs out again, simply navigate to your `LoginPage`, and as the `NoHistory = true` the MasterDetail will be removed completely.

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = false, NoHistory = true)]
public partial class LoginPage : MvxContentPage<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Getting error Cannot replace mainpage.